# print observable array in console is not working in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I tried to print the observable array in console.log. But it prints like `object, object` for all array items.

I have posted the codes below:

**ts file:**

```
   private stuArr: ObservableArray<StudentData> = new ObservableArray<StudentData>();


  ngOnInit() {  

        this.fileReader.getArrayDataFromLocalFile('/json/students.json')
            .subscribe(data => {

              this.stuArr.push(data.students.map(item => new StudentData(item.name, item.id, item.address)));
              console.log("PrintData :", this.stuArr);             

            });
    }
```

Comment: ObservableArray is a class. You can call its toString() method, and see if it won't print the elements in sequence. If it doesn't, then you may have to iterate through the object's elements with a forEach

Comment: you need to use `console.log("PrintData :", JSON.stringify(this.allFeedItems));`

Comment: @RahulSingh I tried stringify already.getting typeerror converting circular structure to json error in console at runtime

Comment: you need to log this in console or template ? if not you can try iterating thought the entire array and then show the objects

Comment: @RahulSingh console only not template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can print the observable array using for loop iterator or else by tns debug android or ios using chrome devtools:

```
  printArr(stuData:ObservableArray<StudentData>){
    for(let i=0; i<stuData.length; i++)
    console.log("PrintData:", stuData.getItem(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("*** PrintData start ***", );
console.dir(this.stuArr);
console.log("*** PrintData end ***", );
```

Comment: console.dir takes an object as argument, so console.dir("PrintData :", this.stuArr) for instance wont work.